# Error when trying to install extensions via VScode on my Chromebook: “ Error scanning user extensions: Unexpected token '#', "#!/bin/bas"... ”

Tags: installation, visual-studio-code, extension

When I am trying to install extensions within VScode on my Chromebook. It shows me an error message"please check for the log details.

When I clicked on the log, the message was:

```
2024-03-02 15:03:21.576 [info] Started local extension host with PID 3122.
2024-03-02 15:03:24.631 [error] Error scanning user extensions: Unexpected token '#', "#!/bin/bas"... is not valid
```

Comment: What is this extension and where did you get it?

Comment: its pretty clear that your extension contains a bash script, and assumes that the system its installed upon knows how to process a shebang. if your system does not have a bash environment, or natively understand a shebang, then the system is not compatible.